# Terraform unable to import transit gateway route

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to import an existing transit gateway route to my terraform project.
my setup is like this:

```
    resource "aws_ec2_transit_gateway" "tgw" {
      description = "gateway for vpn"
      
      tags = {
        "Name" = "openvpn-gateway"
        "managed_by_terraform" = "true"
      }
    }
    
    resource "aws_ec2_transit_gateway_vpc_attachment" "tgw-attachments-private-vpc" {
      transit_gateway_id = aws_ec2_transit_gateway.tgw.id
      vpc_id = var.private-vpc-id
    
      subnet_ids = var.private-vpc-subnets
    
      tags = {
        "Name" = "private-vpc-gateway-attachment"
        "managed_by_terraform" = "true"
      }
    }
    
    resource "aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route_table" "tgw-route-table" {
      transit_gateway_id = aws_ec2_transit_gateway.tgw.id
    
      tags = {
        "Name" = "openvpn-gateawy-route-table"
        "managed_by_terraform" = "true"
      }
    }
    
   resource "aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route" "private-vpc-route" {
      destination_cidr_block = var.private-vpc-cidr
      transit_gateway_attachment_id = aws_ec2_transit_gateway_vpc_attachment.tgw-attachments-private-vpc.id
      transit_gateway_route_table_id = aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route_table.tgw-route-table.id
    }
```

And this configuration is on a module named gateway, for the import command I tried:

> terraform import
> 'module.gateway.aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route.private-vpc-route'
> 'tgw-rtb-xxx_10.0.0.0/16'

as the documentation says at this page: [documantation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ec2_transit_gateway_route)

but I am getting the following error:

> Error: Cannot import non-existent remote object │  │ While attempting
> to import an existing object to
> "module.gateway.aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route.private-vpc-route", the
> provider detected that no object exists with the given id. Only
> pre-existing objects can be imported; check that the id is correct and
> that it is associated with the provider's configured region or │
> endpoint, or use "terraform apply" to create a new remote object for
> this resource.

I have double checked transit gateway route table id and destination cidr block and active region.

edit: This is how I use the module:

```
module "vpc" {
  source      = "../modules/vpc"
  public-subnets-name = var.public-subnets-name
  public-subnets-cidr = var.public-subnets-cidr
  private-cidr = var.private-cidr
  private-subnets-name = var.private-subnets-name
  private-subnets-cidr = var.private-subnets-cidr
  igw-id = module.gateway.igw-id
  private-igw-id = module.gateway.private-igw-id
  tg-id = module.gateway.tgw-id
  pcx-id = var.pcx-id
  nat-id = module.gateway.nat-id
  development-private-vpc-cidr = var.development-private-vpc-cidr
}

module "gateway" {
  source = "../modules/gateway"
  public-vpc-id = module.vpc.public-vpc-id
  public-vpc-cidr = var.public-cidr
  private-vpc-id = module.vpc.private-vpc-id
  private-vpc-cidr = var.private-cidr
  nat-subnet = module.vpc.private-vpcs_public-subnet-id
  nat-allocation = var.nat-allocation
  private-vpc-subnets = module.vpc.private-vpc-subnet_ids
  public-vpc-subnets = module.vpc.public-vpc-subnet_ids
}
```

Comment: Seems terraform is looking in a different account and region. You configuration and command otherwise look correct.

Comment: I can successfully import other resources like transit gateway and route table I don't think that's the issue

Comment: @ÇağrıBIYIK can you add the module call to the question?

Comment: @MarkoE i have edited the question and added my main.tf file entirely

Comment: Bit surprised by the `│ │` in the error, like it isn't seeing your import address. Maybe there is a bug in the provider at the version you're using. I'd consider opening a bug on the AWS provider if you're using the latest version, or trying the latest version if you aren't.

Comment: I thinks that is the red line at the left of the message so just a copy error here its the image of error : https://imgur.com/a/YYd2eYE I will open a bug at aws provider

Comment: Created an issue on aws provider if you have this problem too please upvote: [issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/29545)